# I lost my login details and cannot find it anymore

Tags: support, login

My profile is: https://stackoverflow.com/users/131609/aamirafridi-com
I forgot both username and password. Please help me.

Answer (score 7):

From what you've posted, this doesn't sound that different from claiming, "I've forgotten my username and password, the account is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)".

You should consult [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help), and probably contact the site staff directly using [this form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other).

I could also recommend you searching through your e-mail addresses to find the registration e-mail from Stack Exchange, then you will know the login, and will be able to recover the password.

Comment: I'd have preferred getting Jeff's account instead ^_^